# Grouping Blocked Data

Tags: r, anova, blocking

I have data from an experiment where participants performed a task many times. I arrange the trials into blocks so that 32 trials make up a block and I have 8 blocks. It was a between subjects experiment with 8 participants per condition and 4 conditions.

I measured whether a participant successfully completed the task or not (0 or 1) so a row of data looks like:

> participant, condition, block, trial, completed

I then group trials into blocks, computing the rate at which they complete it:

> participant, condition, block, completed_rate

An analysis of block shows that block has no effect from block 4 to 8, as a result we analyse only those blocks. When looking at the graph there is a clear trend and it appears by the error bars to be significant. However, when I run an ANOVA using ezANOVA, it is not significant.

```
m <- ezANOVA(data = df, 
      wid = participant, 
      dv = completed, 
      between = condition,
      return_aov=TRUE)
```

ezANOVA complains "Collapsing data to cell means."
When I use aov though, I get a significant result:

```
aov(completed ~ condition, data=df)
```

I suspect ezANOVA is complaining because in my data I have multiple rows per participant. Is there a way I can use those extra rows without ezANOVA complaining? I'd like to use as much of my data as possible as it is somewhat noisy.